# Need aggregate data AND distinct data, should i use 2 queries or treat hundeds of thousands rows ? (best practice)

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have 2 tables
1. First table contains prospects, their treatment status and the mail code they received (see it as a foreign key)
2. Second table contains mails, indexed with email code

I need to display some charts about hundreds of thousands prospects so I was thinking about an aggregate query (get prospect data group by month, count status positive, count status negative, between start and end date, etc)
Result is pretty short and simple, and I can use it directly in charts :

```
[ "2019-01" => [ "WON" => 55000, "LOST" => 85000, ...],
 ...
]
```

Then I was asked to add a filter with mails (code and human label) so user would chose it from a multi select field. I can handle writting the query(ies), but I am wondering about which way I should use.

I got a choice between: 
- keeping my first query and do a second one (distinct values of mail, same conditions)
- query everything and treat all my rows with PHP

I know coding but I have little knowledge about performance.
In theory I should not use 2 queries about same data but treating all those lines with php when mysql can do it better, looks like ... "overkill".

Is there a best practice ?

Answer (score -1):

I have a lot of PHP pages that have *dozens* of queries supporting them, and they run plenty fast.  When a page does not run fast, I focus on the slowest query; I do not on playing games in PHP.  But I avoid running a query that hits hundreds of thousands of rows; it will be "too" slow.  Some things...

- Maybe I will find a way to aggregate the data to avoid a big scan.
- Maybe I will move the big query to a second page -- this avoids penalizing the user who does not need.
- Maybe I will break up the big scan so that the user must ask for pieces, *not* build a page with 100K lines.  Pagination is *not* good for that many rows.  So...
- Maybe I will dynamically build an index into a second level of pages.

To discuss this further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, some `SELECTs` (not worrying about how bad they are; we'll tell you), and mockups of page(s).

Comment: Hi Rick James. I get the point that I need to avoid handling so many rows php side. So basically I need 2 kinds of data : main one is aggregate . And FOR NOW I need another kind of data that is distinct list of a column values so I can display filter fields to user. In near future I am pretty sure that client will ask me to add more distinct values for more filters so I was searching for a scalable way to accomplish this. If I understand there is no rule, I need to be "reasonable" (that is not "scallable compatible" ;)). In conclusion, at this point I will do the 2 queries. Thanks

Comment: Beware, the future requirements may lead you down the quagmire called EAV.

Comment: Hi @Rick James. For non-english readers (like me !), [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) Thanks for the information about design pattern and to be a quagmire ;)